# Compiling app using Vmware OSX

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, react-native, virtual-machine

I am trying to learn react Native for IOS development... I have researched a lot about Swift vs React native and came to this decision. 
The question is I am poor as hell. But got a good PC. And I can run VMware OSX in my PC. 
I understand that I can install an run Xcode and all that. But I am getting the question whether I can upload my app to an Iphone or Also Can I upload it to Apple Store using my VMware? There is a word comes up like final compiling can't be done without a Mac and All that. Since I got it using a VM is confusing and difficult and also slow. But still I can't spend on a MAC right now. But I have to learn and upload app into the Apple Store along with testing it on an Iphone. 
So the question is, Is it a problem using VMware OSX to do these things?
please help, I researched a lot but could't get these things :)
TIA.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is **YES**. You can make apps with VMware and upload them to App Store with no problems. I’ve done it myself previously.

However, since it is a virtual machine without full graphics support, you cannot simulate and run graphics-related apps and tools that use the GPU. For example,

- You cannot use Simulator properly for iOS 11+
- You cannot debug view hierarchy since it uses GPU for rendering and
  debugging UI elements
- You cannot debug SpriteKit or SceneKit projects properly etc.
- AirPlay and AirDrop won’t work.

Other than those, you can do almost everything in a VMware macOS. For React native, I don’t think there would be a problem compiling apps with it. You are good to go. But as others said, it would be slower than a real Mac, so you have to bear with it.

Comment: Some one told me ... hackintosh will be much greater then the VM?

Comment: Yes, but you need to gather specific hardware components to be able to build it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do anything on your vm like a real mac . It will just be slower depending on your hardware. I installed macOS on a system and got my app to the app store with it.

Comment: SO... Everything is possible in Vmware OSX... There is absolutely no need for a MAC right... I just need an Iphone to test apps in a physical device...I need to hear this because I am waiting for my boss's reply... I just told him that I am gonna learn react native and build IOS apps using VMware only...

Comment: But what was that final compilation thing.. can you explain?? plz

Comment: Yes, once you install and run it on your system, it will be exactly like a macOS on a real MacBook device. I have done it and had no problem. Don't worry about it :)

Comment: macOS on a VM is slower than on a MacBook device. graphics and animations are not as good as a real mac. But if you got a good hardware, there shouldn't be any problem. I recommend you install macOS next to your current OS and not as a VM. It will perform a lot better.

Comment: Are you talking about hackitosh??

Comment: Yes that's what they call it :D

Comment: Okay.. Thanks Brother.. Appreciate your help... #peace :)